# What is an intuitive explanation for something with probability of 0 happening?

Tags: probability

The probability of any continuous random variable taking on a specific value is 0, so every single possible outcome is impossible.

I'm just not really intuitively understanding this. How can something impossible happen?

Comment: "Probability $0$" just doesn't mean "impossible." This is mostly an artifact of how mathematicians choose to deal with continuous random variables, and you can make the argument that it has basically no "real-world" relevance.

Comment: The intuition, such as it is, is throwing a dart at the real line. You have to hit something. But frankly it's not *that* far from the lottery paradox. You shouldn't buy a ticket because it's virtually impossible for you to win. But someone has to win. That's a reasonable finite analog to picking a random real number (from the unit interval, just so we can have a uniform probability measure).

Comment: A simple example, maybe simpler than the case of a continuous random variable, is to think about flipping infinitely many coins. Any particular sequence of coin flips has probability $0$, even though you must flip some sequence. But it's unclear that this matters, since in fact you will never flip infinitely many coins...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The fact that probability 0 does not mean impossible is exactly what I am having trouble grasping. Probability is chance of occurence. If the chance is 0, then I don't see how it can occur.

Comment: @Goldname: The real question is, how can you even tell that a continuous random variable takes a particular value? Any particular value of a continuous random variable requires infinitely many digits to specify, and you somehow have to check that all of them are right. So the situation is actually pretty analogous to the flipping infinitely many coins example. What you can do in practice is check that a random variable takes values in some interval (e.g. check that its first $n$ digits have some particular value), and these sorts of events have nice nonzero probabilities as expected.

Comment: Said another way, the event that a continuous random variable takes a particular value is not really an event in the ordinary intuitive sense - you can't really tell that it happened anyway. It is just a convenient mathematical abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might think of throwing a dart on a target, a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2.$ Unless you have infinite precision measurements, all you can say is that the dart has hit "within $\varepsilon$" for such and such a coordinate, say $(0.02,1.21).$ Almost all real numbers have a nonterminating decimal expansion, which requires infinite precision.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is, say, a standard normal, then the event $X=0$ has probability zero, which means it has no chance whatsoever of occurring. Yet $X=0$ is one of the possible outcomes. I agree that seems odd at first pass.

Every single possible outcome has probability zero? Not really. There's a reason we attribute probabilities to events and not outcomes. So it's true that (if you define an outcome as the exact value of the random variable) the event corresponding to each outcome has probability zero, but there are still plenty of events with nonzero probability, like $-1<X<1.$ I guess in the case with a finite sample space, looking at the outcomes in isolation, each having its own probability is pretty common, but this has to go when making sense of continuous random variables.

Of course, you could be obstinate and choose not to believe in continuous random variables. You might even say that continuous random variables are just limits of discrete random variables and only the latter are well-defined. Then you could split up the real axis into slices of width $dx$ around points $x_i$ and define a discrete random variable $X$ where $P(X=x_i)=f(x_i).$ and $\sum_if(x_i) = 1.$ You could make it look more and more like a standard normal by taking $dx$ smaller and smaller and defining $P(X=x_i)$ on a finer and finer grid. Of course you'd find if as you made $dx$ smaller and smaller that the $P(X=x_i)$ will also get smaller and smaller, limiting down to zero.

Maybe doing this exercise will give you a better feel for why we have $P(X=x)=0$ for a continuous RV and it what sense it is "impossible" that $X=x.$